# Trying to convert "Moves to NewMove (scripts come from unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Creating a pokemon game and trying to make it so that once it meets a certain level criteria a new move will be unlocked with that level to replace a base move.
I tried to making the NewMoves list public as I was told that was the error however it did not help and repeatedly said that it cannot convert them.

````
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pokemon 
{
    Pokemon_Data _Data;
    int level;

    public int HP {get; set;}

    [field: SerializeField] public List<NewMove> Moves {get; private set;}

    
    public Pokemon(Pokemon_Data pData, int pLevel)
    {
        _Data = pData;
        level = pLevel;
        HP = _Data.MaxHP;

        Moves = new List<NewMove>();
        foreach (var move in _Data.NewMoves)
        {
            if (move.Level <= level)
            Moves.Add(new Moves(move.Base));
            
            if (Moves.Count >= 4)
            break;

    

        
    }
    //Pokemon formula to calculate stat increase through levels
    public int Attack
    {
        get{ return Mathf.FloorToInt((_Data.Attack * level) /100f) + 5; }
    }
     public int Defense
    {
        get{ return Mathf.FloorToInt((_Data.Defense * level) /100f) + 5; }
    }
     public int SpAttack
    {
        get{ return Mathf.FloorToInt((_Data.SpAttack * level) /100f) + 5; }
    }
     public int SpDefense
    {
        get{ return Mathf.FloorToInt((_Data.SpDefense * level) /100f) + 5; }
    }
     public int Speed
    {
        get{ return Mathf.FloorToInt((_Data.Speed * level) /100f) + 10; }
    }
}
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Move", menuName = "Pokemon/Create new move") ]
public class Move_Data : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] string name;
    [TextArea]
    [SerializeField] string description;

    [SerializeField] PokemonType type;
    [SerializeField] int power;
    [SerializeField] int accuracy;
    [SerializeField] int pp;

     public string Name
    {
        get {return name;}
    }
    public string Description
    {
        get {return description;}
    }
       public PokemonType Type
    {
        get {return type;}
    }
       public int Power
    {
        get {return power;}
    }
         public int Accuracy
    {
        get {return accuracy;}
    }
         public int PP
    {
        get {return pp;}
    }

}

```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Moves 
{
    public Move_Data Base { get; set; }
    public int PP { get; set; }
    public Moves(Move_Data pData)
    {
        Base = pData;
        PP = pData.PP;

    }

   
}   


```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Pokemon", menuName = "Pokemon/Create new pokemon") ]

public class Pokemon_Data : ScriptableObject
{
    //Pokedec Entries
    [SerializeField] string name;
    [TextArea]
    [SerializeField] string description;
    [SerializeField] Sprite frontSprite;
    [SerializeField] Sprite backSprite;
    [SerializeField] PokemonType type1;
    [SerializeField] PokemonType type2;
    
    //Base stats
    [SerializeField] int maxHP;
    [SerializeField] int attack;
    [SerializeField] int defense;
    [SerializeField] int spAttack;
    [SerializeField] int spDefense;
    [SerializeField] int speed;

    [SerializeField] public List<NewMove> newMoves; 
 

    public string Name
    {
        get {return name;}
    }
    public string Description
    {
        get {return description;}
    }
    public Sprite FrontSprite
    {
        get {return frontSprite;}
    }
    public Sprite BackSprite
    {
        get {return backSprite;}
    }
    public PokemonType Type1
    {
        get {return type1;}
    }
    public PokemonType Type2
    {
        get {return type2;}
    }
    public int MaxHP
    {
        get {return maxHP;}
    }
    public int Attack
    {
        get {return attack;}
    }
    public int Defense
    {
        get {return defense;}
    }
    public int SpAttack
    {
        get {return spAttack;}
    }
    public int SpDefense
    {
        get {return spDefense;}
    }
    public int Speed
    {
        get {return speed;}
    }

    public List<NewMove> NewMoves
    { 
        get {return newMoves;   }
    }

}

[System.Serializable]
public class NewMove
{
    [SerializeField] Move_Data moveBase;
    [SerializeField] int level;

    public NewMove(Move_Data moveBase, int level)
    {
       this.moveBase = moveBase;
       this.level = level;
    }

    public Move_Data Base
    {
        get {return moveBase;}
    }
      public int Level
    {
        get {return level;}
    }
}
public enum PokemonType
{
    None,
    Normal,
    Fire,
    Water,
    Electric,
    Grass,
    Ice,
    Fighting,
    Poision,
    Ground,
    Flying,
    Pschic,
    Bug,
    Rock,
    Ghost,
    Dragon,
    Steel,
    Fairy,
}

```
``
````

Comment: It seems like you're not understanding [types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/). Just becuase you think two types should be interchangable dosn't mean they are, unless you tell the compiler they are. It would be like trying to put a car in a list of animals, the compiler won't let you. You will need to have some base type that both `Move` and `NewMove` inherit from to do that. But really why is `NewMove` a different type to `Move`? Making something a different type means its fundamentally different, `NewMove` just seems like should be a type of `Move` to me?

Comment: Yea that is what NewMove is supposed to be. I'm trying to get it to replace Move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a type of `Moves` to a list of `NewMove` because they are different types with no relation to each other.

Inside your `Pokemon` constructor, replace

```
Moves.Add(new Moves(move.Base));
```

with

```
Moves.Add(new NewMove(move.Base, /*level*/));
```